# R - Parsing keywords from udpipe RAKE per article back to dataframe

Tags: r, nlp, udpipe

I'm attempting to use udpipe's RAKE to generate a list of 25 RAKE tokens per document in a dataframe and write those tokens (plus a simple str_count) back to the dataframe. I constructed a for loop to handle, but instead I'm writing the same result to every line, instead of different results to each line.

Packages installed and used are udpipe, dplyr, stringi, stringr, data.table.

```
annotation$length <- nchar(annotation$token)

annotation <- annotation %>% filter(length >= 3 )

counter <- textdf$doc_id

for (i in counter) {
  subannotation <- annotation %>% filter(doc_id == i)
  stats <-
    keywords_rake(
      x = subannotation,
      term = "token", #token or lemma
      group = "doc_id",
      ngram_max = 3,
      n_min = 1,
      relevant = subannotation$upos %in% c("NOUN", "VERB", "ADV", "ADJ")
    )
  stats <- stats %>% top_n(25,rake)
  checktopics <- paste(stats$keyword, collapse =  " ")
  textdf$topics <- checktopics
  textdf$score <- str_count(checktopics,"cheese")

}
```

The intended outcome should be something like:

```
id score topics
1  12    chocolate chocoholics cheese
2  1     plastic waste cheese
3  3     neuroscientists data system
```

The current outcome is:

```
id score topics
1  3     neuroscientists data system
2  3     neuroscientists data system
3  3     neuroscientists data system
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Please create a complete reproducible example. We don't have access to the `annotation` object and the `textdf` object. Or use a built in dataset from udpipe to show what you want.

Comment: You should really have a look at txt_recode_ngram which is part of the udpipe R package. It allows to recode text to keywords which are either identified with rake/collocations/textrank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate fix is to add the pointer to the line in the loop. Derp.

```
textdf$topics[i] <- checktopics
textdf$score[i] <- str_count(checktopics,"cheese")
```